# get the page template unique from the slug in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hi i have this page template past conferences single and i have this href tag

```
<a href="/past-conferences-single/<?php the_slug(); ?>" class="wrapper" style="background-image:url('<?=$url?>')">
```

and my href link goes this way

```
past-conference-single/2013-inagural-diversity-abroad-conference-5/
```

i want that when i click on this page goes to this page template past-conference-single and with the content is dynamic based on the slug.
How will i able to do this?
Any help is muchly appreiciated. TIA

Comment: So much confusing question. Show here some piece of code

Comment: I can solve your problem

Comment: i mean i have this page template "past-conference-single" and i have this href tag and i want to get that past-conference-single page based from my href link like this one 
past-conference-single/2013-inagural-diversity-abroad-conference-5/
and after clicking to that page goes to my past-conference-single page

Comment: past-conference-single/2013-inagural-diversity-abroad-conference-5/ this is a post?

Comment: yes a post from this one
<a href="/past-conferences-single/<?php the_slug(); ?>"

Comment: and when i click i want that it will take me to the page template "past-conference-single

Comment: here is my link
http://eventsitebeta.esy.es/past-conferences/
i have 4 boxes and when i click on that link i want to use this template
http://eventsitebeta.esy.es/past-conferences-single/
pls help

Comment: single-post-type.php I think you want this . change only post-type with your post type

Comment: where will i change my post-type?

Comment: can yo help me where will i change my post-type? file?

Comment: man you goto the themes/your-theme/single-post-type.php then create single-post-type.php file

Comment: okay ill create a single-post-type.php file then how will i able to call onto that pagE?